Python Tkinter: I want to get a save an input into a variable when button is pushed but the Programm keeps crashing. text = self.entry.get()
I have a Function in a class. This Function creates an input box as well as a button using tkinter. When the Button is pushed, I want to save the input of the input box in a Variable called "Platzhalter". My Annotations are in German so I hope that`s not a Problem.
class SchätzFrage:
    #hier werden einige Variablen und Listen erstellt, die innerhalb der Klasse in mehreren Funktionen aufgerufen werden
    def __init__(self, root, NamensListe):
        self.root = root
        self.Fragestellung = ""
        self.Antwort = ""
        self.Erklärung = ""
        self.Runde = 1
        self.AntwortListe = [""] * 2
        self.NamensListe = NamensListe
        self.PlatzHalter = ""


    def Auswählen(self):  #Diese Funktion wird bei einem Unentschieden Aufgerufen, sie wählt die Schätzfrage zufällig aus
        
        FragenAuswahl = FragenKatalog.get("Schätzfrage", [])    #Hier werden die Fragen aus der Kategorie "Schätzfrage" in eine Liste gespeichert "FragenAuswahl",
        AusgewaehlteFrage = random.choice(FragenAuswahl)        #aus der dann eine zufällige Frage ausgewählt wird

        #Hier werden Fragestellung, richtige Antwort und Erklärung aus dem Wörterbuch AusgewaehlteFrage in jeweils eigene Variablen abgespeichert
        self.Fragestellung = AusgewaehlteFrage["Frage"]
        self.Antwort = AusgewaehlteFrage["Antwort"]
        self.Erklärung = AusgewaehlteFrage["Erklärung"]

        self.BenutzerOberfläche()    #ruft die Funktion Benutzeroberfläche innerhalb der Klasse Self auf


    def BenutzerOberfläche(self):   #erzeugt die Benutzeroberfläche der Schätzfrage

        #alle vorherigen widgets werden gelöscht
        for widget in self.root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        #ein Label mit der Fragestellung wird erstellt
        FragestellungLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text=self.Fragestellung)
        FragestellungLabel.pack(pady=10)

        #dieses Label gibt an, welcher Spieler am Zug ist
        SpielerAmZugLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text="%s gib deine Antwort ein!" % self.NamensListe[self.Runde %2])
        SpielerAmZugLabel.pack(pady=10)

        #Eingabefeld für die Antwort
        self.AntwortEingabe = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.AntwortEingabe.pack(pady=5)

        #Knopf zum Bestätigen der eigenen Antwort
        BestätigungsKnopf = tk.Button(self.root, text="Antwort bestätigen", command=self.AntwortBestätigen)
        BestätigungsKnopf.pack(pady=20)


    def AntwortBestätigen(self):

        #print("hi")
        self.PlatzHalter = self.AntwortEingabe.get()  #speichert die eingegebene Antwort zwischen
        print(self.PlatzHalter)


https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Is there an error traceback? If so, please edit your question to include it.

no there`s no error traceback

You say that the program crashed, but also that there was no error traceback.  What exactly happened, then?

did you run it in console/terminal to see error message?

with English annotations and English variables would be simpler ;) And it would be simpler if you would use lower_case_names for functions and variables. See more: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

I tried to recreate minimal working code and it gives me error NameError: name 'FragenKatalog' is not defined in console/terminal

Your code calls FragenKatalog.get() but you haven't defined FragenKatalog anywhere.
